# How to update list order without reorder list?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have following items in sql-server table. (size > 100K)

```
Name   Order
x      1
...    n
y      25
...    n
z      300
...    n
```

When change order of item, (z=25) I need reorder all items (x=1,z=25,y=26) My solution is using decimal order column and calculate new order with this formula: "(previous order + next order) / 2" (x=1,z=24.5,y=25) for changed order item. This solution ok, but decimal precision increment every change order. (if changed before)

Is there anything method?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do you get from `[1, 25, 26]` to `[1, 24.5, 25]`? Your formula as written shouldn't do that as far as I can tell.

Comment: I guess because "previous order" is 24 because (it's the previous in position to the current 25), "next order" is now 25 and so the result is 24.5.
In my opinion you could implement the data structure as a double linked list where each node element has a property ID that is calculated recursive based on the antecessor of the item. The first one has ID 0. If you also implement a ChangeIndex method (which just swaps the old element on that index with the specified one) you wouldn't have to recalculate all other indizes because they are calculated just on demand.

Comment: @MarkusSafar yes, previous order is 24

Comment: @MarkusSafar any example?

Comment: I missed the fact, that you need to update the data in the sql table. I was thinking of a solution in C# - Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a data structure. Data in list are ordered, so when you insert 'z' before y e.g:

```
MyList.Remove('z')
MyList.Insert(MyList.IndexOf('y'), 'z');
```

Then list is reorderd:

```
MyList.IndexOf('z');  //will return 25
MyList.IndexOf('y');  //will return 26
```

You can get access to these value by:

```
MyList[25];  //will return 'z'
MyList[26];  //will return 'y'
```

Notice that List is indexed from 0 not from 1.